# Input int list in Python 3

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

I tried to change from Python 2.7 to 3.3.1

I want to input

```
1 2 3 4
```

and output in

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

In 2.7 I can use

```
score = map(int,raw_input().split())
```

What should I use in Python 3.x?

Answer (score 28):

Use `input()` in Python 3. `raw_input` has been renamed to `input` in Python 3 . And `map` now returns an iterator instead of list.

```
score = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

or :

```
score = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you can use the [`2to3` tool](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) that ships with Python to at least point you in the right direction as far as porting goes:

```
$ echo "score = map(int, raw_input().split())" | 2to3 - 2>/dev/null
--- <stdin> (original)
+++ <stdin> (refactored)
@@ -1,1 +1,1 @@
-score = map(int, raw_input().split())
+score = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

The output isn't necessarily idiomatic (a list comprehension would make more sense here), but it will provide a decent starting point.